# MySQL Warning EXIT handler ignored for Data truncation

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In below stored procedure in MYSQL, whenever there is a warning due to data-truncation, it shows warning. But it does not ROLLBACK anything. The EXIT handler for WARNING is completely getting ignored. Please help.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `saveDetails` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`dbuser`@`%` PROCEDURE `saveDetails`(IN param_name VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;
    START TRANSACTION;
        UPDATE userDetails SET displaystatus = 2 where displaystatus = 1;
        UPDATE userDetails SET displaystatus = 1 where displaystatus = 0;
        UPDATE userDetails SET name = param_name;
    COMMIT;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I tried below version as well, but this also does not work:

DELIMITER $$

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `saveDetails` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`dbuser`@`%` PROCEDURE `saveDetails`(IN param_name VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING  
    BEGIN 
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    START TRANSACTION;
        UPDATE userDetails SET displaystatus = 2 where displaystatus = 1;
        UPDATE userDetails SET displaystatus = 1 where displaystatus = 0;
        UPDATE userDetails SET name = param_name;
    COMMIT;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

With a very simple example like this:

```sql
/*Table structure for table `mytable` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mytable`;

CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/*Data for the table `mytable` */

INSERT  INTO `mytable`(`value`) VALUES (100);

/* Procedure structure for procedure `saveDetails` */

/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `saveDetails` */;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `saveDetails`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;
    START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE `mytable` SET `value` = 'A' WHERE `id` = 1;
    COMMIT;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Everything works as expected:

```sql
mysql> SELECT `id`, `value` FROM `mytable`;
+----+-------+
| id | VALUE |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   100 |
+----+-------+
1 ROW IN SET (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL saveDetails;
QUERY OK, 0 ROWS affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `value` FROM `mytable`;
+----+-------+
| id | VALUE |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   100 |
+----+-------+
1 ROW IN SET (0.02 sec)
```

You can show: `SHOW CREATE TABLE userDetails;`?